# Return file from request framework7

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, download

I am trying to create a script for downloading files through a web app, for now I am concentrating on the script server then I will switch to cordova for phones.

Code i tried:

**Javascript:**

```
$f7.request({
  method: 'POST',
  url: urlofwebsite + 'api/getFile.php',
  crossDomain: true,
  data: {
    fakeid: idoffile,
    iduser: iduser, // check for security reason
    time: timeoflogin // check for security reason
  },
  success: function(data, status, xhr) {
    var blob = new Blob([data], {
      type: 'application/pdf'
    });
    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    var fileName = 'test.pdf';
    var urllink = url;
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = urllink;
    link.download = fileName;
    link.click();
  }
});
```

**PHP:**

```
$file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$res['url'];
readfile($file);
```

By manually specifying the extension and file type (just for test it), the file **from the blob** is downloaded but completely blank.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but as you should know by now (given your reputation level) it's not required to leave a comment - if you hover your mouse over the downvote button you can see a summary of the reasons why downvotes may be given, and you can also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down for more information.

Comment: Anyway your PHP code doesn't seem to make a lot of sense. You seem to be setting some headers to enable the download, but then you're trying to return JSON data instead of the file. I'd expect you can replace everything from `$data = file_get_contents($file);` onwards with just `readFile($file);` and get much better results. You can't return JSON _and_ the file (unless you base64 encode the file data, but that's not very efficient). In case of problems - e.g. the file does not exist - then  just set a suitable HTTP status code - e.g. 404 - instead.

Comment: P.S. It's unclear what `$file - > returnFile();` is / does or how it fits into the rest of the code, as it's been shown out of context, and `$file` in the rest of the code is clearly a string, not an object. It's confusing, and you haven't really explained it in your post.

Comment: "The most obvious problem is that I cannot directly use the data from file_get_contents" - why is that an obvious problem? Also, is this a Javascript, or a PHP problem?

Comment: `I can't know / return the file extension and even less the name, correct?`...no. You're supplying that information to the Javascript in the response headers (specifically in the `Content-Disposition` header).

Comment: This: `header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");` makes no sense. You can only set any given header once - with this code you're just overwriting the header each time you run the command. And you're then setting a mime-type which isn't valid. Either use `$mime` as the content-type value, or set a generic (but valid) one such as `application/octet-stream`.

Comment: "I've tried" - and what happens? Also, please add **all clarification** to your question by editing it

Comment: Apart from that these multiple Content-Type headers make no sense, not one of those is actually the _correct_ one. You are returning JSON to the client, so it should say `application/json` to begin with.

Comment: "i have a error about parse" - whatever that means: if you want others to help you fix that error, you need to share the error message

Comment: "the file is created but completely blank" - what does that mean? Where do you create a file? As far as I see, you solely read files. And through checking your browser's network console, you could check whether reading the file on the server already fails, or handling the response in your JS code

Comment: Creating a blob doesn't create a file, it creates a blob. So no, it's not clear! Your description will be much easier to understand if you use terminology correctly, and give more precise indication of what code you are referring to when you are describing something.

Comment: Ok but that makes all our earlier comments make no sense. Not helpful. It should be possible to see the progression of the code.

Comment: @ADyson They are direct comments to me so not relevant to the community, I start deleting mine.

Comment: `but completely blank`...have you looked in your browser's Network tool to see what the raw response to the AJAX request is? Does it contain the file data? (Try with a simple text file to begin with, then it's easy to check the content, obviously with binary files you'd still see output but it's harder to verify the content.). That way you'll know if the PHP part is working correctly or not, which helps to narrow down the issue. That's a fairly basic debugging step really.

Comment: I tried `console.log(data)`, the "raw" printed, but honestly I can't figure out if there are any words inside (it's full of symbol/letter etc.)

Comment: @ADyson I tried without the "request" directly on the server and it didn't work, adding the header it works so theoretically the file is correct

Comment: `I can't figure out if there are any words inside (it's full of symbol/letter etc.)`...sounds like the content of a binary file. That's why I suggested to test with a simple text file first, but I guess you didn't follow that suggestion.

Comment: `adding the header it works`...what header? Added where? Please, always give precise descriptions. Vague ones are no use to us at all - we cannot see your screen or read your mind to know exactly what you actually did. "didn't work" is also completely useless as a piece of information.

Comment: @ADyson Sorry I didn't understand, I tried and the text file is read correctly.

Comment: I think you should remove `dataType: 'json'` from the AJAX options - that could cause your AJAX client to try and interpret the downloaded data as JSON, which it no longer is.

Comment: P.S. Your frontend Blob and download code works properly, if provided with some valid data - demo: https://jsfiddle.net/z9Lhkmw0/

Comment: Finally we did it, I had already removed the `json` part, in practice the framework I am using has the ability to use the specifications of the `XMLHttpRequest` in fact adding `responseType` with the value `blob` reads me the file correctly. Well what can I say thank you for your patience. One last thing before you told me that I can send the `mime` and the file extension in the response, do I have to use the `header` in php?

Comment: You mean in the response, not the request. And yes you would use the response headers for that, which you would set using PHP's `header` command.

Comment: @ADyson I tried header `Content-Disposition` and `Content-type`, the first one is not pass to response, the second one work as expect. I read about cors but i don't understand how access `Content-Disposition` without violate the cors.

Comment: That sounds like a topic worthy of a whole new question, it might easily be of interest to others having that specific issue.

Comment: Yes it's true, i will :) thanks for now.

Answer (score 1):

thanks to @ADyson for help, i can provide a community wiki answer:

Besides the various basic problems such as `header` etc. in my question, there was a fundamental trick which is adding this command to the request:

```
xhrFields: { responseType: 'blob' }
```

In the php file instead just use:

```
$file = PATHTOFILE; readfile($file);
```